# Magento customer dedicated confirmation page - with working confirmation

Tags: magento, confirmation

New customers receive an email in which they have to click on the confirmation link. This link should put the customer to the account-page with the message "hey, your account is now confirmed"... How could I tell Magento to show the user an alternative page without lead him to the regular page?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Sounds like you'd have to extend a core controller to send the user to your new page.

Comment: I will give it a try to change the core-controller. If I am successful I post my solution here.